# Cannot ssh after rebooting VPS

Tags: ssh, vps, ovh

I reboot my VPS just now then when I logged in via ssh it says permission denied after inputting my password. I have an OVH linux VPS and I can log into it using KVM from the panel. I didn't set any ssh key and I am wondering what might be the cause. My OS/distribution is Debian 7 (Wheezy) (64-bit version).

Answer (score 1):

Log into server using using KVM and check the below listed things.

```
vim /etc/ssh/sshd_config
```

find the below lines **PasswordAuthentication** if its commented than uncomment it or change it to **yes** from **no**

```
#PasswordAuthentication yes
#PermitEmptyPasswords no
PasswordAuthentication yes
```

Now check wheather status of ssh service is up and running if its not then

```
 service ssh status
 service ssh start
 chkconfig ssh on  ( using this service atomatically comes up on next reboot)
```

Comment: If this is an EL based system, then the standard sshd_config file generally lists the defaults but comments them out so your first point may be unnecessary. The chkconfig command is generally only useful for EL based systems <=6 or EL7 based systems with non native system services. The systemctl command should be used in this case. Anyway this is all moot as the OP doesn't say which OS/distro they are using.

Comment: yes, no OS was defined so just given an idea. @lain you can edit this, always posts of seniors are much helpful.

Comment: @imvikasmunjal I tried your method but it still says permission denied. I add my OS/distribution in my post. After I logging into KVM, I delete the root password, but when I log in via ssh, it still asks for root password. I've tried all the password I know but it doesn't work.

Comment: try to telnet the port which you are using for ssh, are you able to telnet it from your local system?